# Multiple Camera Nodes

Tags: stereo, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use two basler cameras in a stereo configuration, utilizing the pylon_camera module to grab frames. My cameras use the USB3.0 interface. I'm struggling to connect to both camera's simultaneously because they have identical DeviceUserID's (daA1280-54uc). How can I change the DeviceUserID's of the cameras such that they will have unique values?

Unfortunately since they don't use the GigE interface, I don't believe that I can use IPConfigurator to accomplish this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277903/multiple-camera-nodes/) by [MEDS](https://answers.ros.org/users/32957/meds/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-12-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried to run

> rosrun pylon_camera write_device_user_id_to_camera cam_1

when only a single camera is attached to your computer to write the device_user_id?

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MEDS](https://answers.ros.org/users/32957/meds/) on 2017-12-20**:
That's what I needed. I wish this that this was made more clear in the documentation.